# linux rpc: Varint for protobuf encoding : not expected value

Tags: linux, encoding, protocol-buffers

I'm using google protocol buffer library with:

```
$protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

I search internet and it says the value encoding of a integer consists of multibytes that each byte 1st bit, is the indicator to say whether the encoding should continue to another byte. My understanding:

For a number 101 (0x65), it has only 1 byte, so its encoded value is still 0x65
For a number 0x6565, as long as it has 2 bytes, and intel uses little endian, the 1st byte should modify its first bit to be 1, and thus 0x65+0x80=0xe5, so the whole integer will have 2 bytes, and should become

```
0x65e5
```

This is my expectation. but I tested with my sample program. First I tried to set a "0x65" value to log7.data, and set "0x6565" to log8.data, and use xxl command to check them

```
cat 7.proto
message hello 
{ 
    required int32 f1=1;
}

$cat 7.cpp
#include "7.pb.h"
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream f("./log7.data",ios::binary|ios::out);
    hello p;
    p.set_f1(0x65);
    p.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    return 0;
}

$cat 8.cpp
#include ".pb.h"
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream f("./log8.data",ios::binary|ios::out);
    hello p;
    p.set_f1(0x6565);
    p.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    return 0;
}
```

Check the output:

```
$protoc 7.proto --cpp_out=./
g++ 7.cpp 7.pb.cc -lprotobuf && ./a.out && xxd log7.data
00000000: 0865                                     .e

$protoc 8.proto --cpp_out=./
$g++ 8.cpp 8.pb.cc -lprotobuf && ./a.out && xxd log8.data
00000000: 08e5 ca01                                ....
```

You can see, for log8.data, I expect it to be "08e5 65", but it's actually "08e5 ca01". How to explain this value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to split by 7 bit and add first bit

```
0x6565 => to binary
0b110010101100101 => split by 7 bit
0b1 1001010 1100101 => add first bit except first
0b1 11001010 11100101 => now show in hex
0x01cae5
```